# How run aspect in Spring without xml?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, aspect

### How to run an aspect in Java.

How to run an aspect in **Spring** using annotations, without *xml* file?

Many other tutorials using xml file for configuration ascpect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a custom annotation;

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE ,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface Loggable {

}
```

Annotate your method that you want to intercept ;

```
@Service
public class MyAwesomeService {

    @Loggable
    public void myAwesomemethod(String someParam) throws Exception {
        // do some awesome things.
    }
}
```

Add aspect dependencies to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and define your aspects class ;

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingHandler {

     @Before("@annotation(com.example.annotation.Loggable)")
     public void beforeLogging(JoinPoint joinPoint){
         System.out.println("Before running loggingAdvice on method=");

    }

    @After("@annotation(com.example.annotation.Loggable)")
    public void afterLogging(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        System.out.println("After running loggingAdvice on method=");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use annotations on your class:
@Component
@Aspect